# Eigen Values and its Relation with Trace and Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition

Trace of a matrix = sum of the eigen values

Determinant of a matrix = product of eigen values.

What are the geometric intuitions behind them? Geometrically speaking, eigen vectors are the vectors which remains on their span even after a transformation and the scalar quantity by which they are scaled or squished is called the eigen values. Determinant on the other hand is the area scaled by the basis vectors. So how these concepts actually connect to each other?

Comment: See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/13526/34894) for geometric interpretations of the trace

Comment: The geometric definition of the determinant is the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by its columns. So I think if you transform the matrix to its eigenbasis, then the lengths of the sides of its spanning parallelepiped become its eigenvalues.

Comment: @Thoth In an eigenbasis, the parallelepiped is a box.